# Is the rule of antlr different from the regular expression of a regular expression?

Tags: antlr4

I am testing the lexical rules of ANTLR, but I found some differences from the rules of the expression being used.

for exmaple.

```
CN  : (CHN|STRING)+;
```

This rule can only match characters beginning with Chinese and characters that cannot match letters.

```
model
   : CN (.*?)  #modelName
   | ID (.*?)  #modelName
   ;
```

This wildcard (.*?) grammar rule can only match the currently defined lexical rules（E.g DOT、NUM、ID、CN）. It cannot match any other character.

```
Formula.g4
grammar Formula;

prog
   : expression
   ;


expression
   : left=expression operator=(MUL | DIV) right=expression                                            # arithmeticBinary
   | left=expression operator=(PLUS | MINUS) right=expression                                         # arithmeticBinary
   | '(' expression ')'                                                                               # parens
   | field                                                                                            # fields
   ;

field
   : model '.' table '.' column                     # physicalField
   | NUM                                            # numeric
   ;

model
   : CN (.*?)  #modelName
   | ID (.*?)  #modelName
   ;

table
   : ID    #tableName
   ;

column
   : ID    #columnId
   ;

SLIDE_OP: DIM_EQ |  DIM_FORWARD_OFFSET | DIM_BACKWARD_OFFSET;
DIM_EQ: '==';
DIM_FORWARD_OFFSET: '<<';
DIM_BACKWARD_OFFSET: '>>';

MUL : '*';
DIV : '/';
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';

EQ  : '=';
NEQ : '<>' | '!=';
LT  : '<';
LTE : '<=';
GT  : '>';
GTE : '>=';

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment STRING : [a-zA-Z0-9_];
fragment CHN : [\u2E80-\u9FFF];


DOT : [#@$%];

NUM : ('-'|'+')?(DIGIT*'.'?DIGIT+);

ID  : STRING+;

CN  : (CHN|STRING)+;

WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

// test case: aaV1.2.3-@#$*.d.b.c
```

I hope that wildcards can match any character。
(CHN|STRING)+  This rule can match strings beginning with Chinese or letters or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inside a parser rule `.` means "any token", not "any character". It is impossible to express the concept of "any character" in parser rules because the parser does not get characters as its input - it gets the tokens produced by the lexer.

What you can do is to define a lexer rule `OTHER: .;` at the end of your grammar¹. This way any unknown character will produce an `OTHER` token, which can then be matched by `.` in the parser rules.

---

¹ This is also a good idea for other reasons, such as turning lexer errors into parser errors that can be handled by the parser's error listener.